# Bad HDD sectors are not getting reallocated

Tags: linux, hard-drive, smart, ext4

I have a few hard drives that have faulty sectors, but when I look at the SMART data using `gnome-disks` I see

```
Reallocated Sector Count    0 sectors
```

From time to time (I guess when it tries to write or read to one of these sectors) the mount goes into read-only mode.

It never seems to flag these sectors as broken. SMART also never says the drive is failing.

I'm talking about a Western Digital drive (WDC WD30EZRX-00DC0B0) and Seagate (ST3000DM001-1ER166)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SMART replaces a sector when the sector at same LBA is written. The SMART attributes that count replaced sectors are often not reliable (often always 0, even after hundreds of sectors have been replaced).

You should rather watch the attributes "current pending sector count" and "offline uncorrectable sectors". They should be at 0 after all faulty sectors have been replaced.

Comment: That's good to know, thanks. Those current RAW_VALUEs are currently at 2166 and 2162 respectively.